# Editing Magento header

Tags: header

I need to edit Magento header by adding an icon and small image telling visitors that we offer Cash-on-Delivery. It should be somewhere around the search bar in the header.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your theme's header template.

This can be found at app/design/$package_name/$theme_name/template/page/html/header.phtml

**$package_name** is the name of the package - e.g. rwd, base

**$theme_name** is the name of the theme (usually default) e.g. default, modern

These values can be found in the admin under System -> Configuration -> General -> Design.

[image]

Please note that depending on where you need to add the icon you may need to edit another template file as it might be a [child block](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-4.html) of the header template.

Comment: I did it by adding the COD details in the header.phtml in line 215 : app->design->frontend->themeName->default->template->page->html->header.phtml

Comment: For proper alignment towards right side i enclosed my icon and text in <div="item item-right hide-below-960">My COD icon with text </div>

Comment: Thats great. Do you need anymore help with finding templates?

Comment: Yes i need some more help.Can you see my asked questions if yes please see my latest asked question.

Comment: That question has now been answered. When I started out with Magento I found Alan Storm's book No Frills Magento Layout to be invaluable with understanding Magento. One other thing you can do which I forgot to mention is if you turn on Template Hints which will tell you where the template is located - http://www.pauldonnelly.net/magento-turning-on-template-path-hints/. If you are happy with my answer can you mark my answer as answered please :)